# how to get the 'sync' icon back

Tags: android-studio

With android studio 3.1.4, it has been working fine but suddenly  the "sync" icon cannot be found anywhere (did not make any change), happens to any projects now.

Also the combox next to the "Run" icon shows red cross and "This configuration cannot edited"

And it has only Project tab does not have the tab of "Android".

Must be some setting messed up. Is there a way

[image]

Comment: hello, whoever down vote it, it would be much helpful it you would share your solution if you knew this problem, or tells why you dont like the question?  I'm running into this problem and couldnt find a solution so asking help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Android plugin got disabled. Please go to Settings | Plugins, find "Android Support" there, check it and restart the IDE.

Comment: thanks a lot, @yole!  it is Android plugin got disabled (dont know how).